# Чем отличается безопасность PDO от безопасности Mysqli?

Tags: php, mysqli, pdo

Привет! Я понимаю, может быть это туповатый вопрос, но все же хочется спросить: есть пока на 15% написаный PHP движок с использованием `mysqli`. Все было норм, но потом мне все начали говорить про `PDO`, что он якобы безопаснее, предотвращает инъекции и прочее. Так вот вопрос: **стоит ли учить PDO и переписывать движок под него** и **почему в PDO безопасность якобы выше? Чем это обусловлено?** Про то, что у `PDO` чуть урезанный функционал, вообще не парит, так как я и 30% функций `mysqli` попросту не юзаю.

Comment: Ни тот, ни другой не защитят вас от самих себя..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В документации есть достаточно [подробные разделы](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysql.php) про это дело

Расширения PDO и mysqli - это не более, чем [API доступа](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) к [выбранной библиотеке БД](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqlinfo.library.choosing.php).

Что PDO, что mysqli предоставляют практически идентичный функционал и, с точки зрения "безопасности и предотвращения инъекций" разницы нет никакой.

Причины, почему имеет смысл использовать PDO:

1) Вам нужны подготовленные запросы на стороне клиента

2) У вас в проекте будут использоваться коннекты к отличным от MySQL базам (postgres например). В таком случае PDO даст единообразность кода для работы с разными БД.

Comment: Да, спасибо. Я понял. Но наверное буду использовать mysqli все таки, просто безопасность придется немного регулярками подправить.

Comment: @EugenEray вот не рекомендовал бы. Обеспечивать безопасность регулярками - это как тушить костер бензином. Что именно вы имеете в виду под безопасностью? В 99.99% случаев достаточно просто использовать подготовленные запросы.

Comment: Да, PDO может быть и лучше (посмотрим, когда выучу), но ведь в .htaccess тоже можно безопасность сделать?

Comment: @EugenEray А причем тут .htaccess вы можете им конечно ограничить доступ к определенным разделам сайта. но причем тут sql-инъекции ? Вы главное _всегда_ все параметры запросов подставляйте в виде `?` и _всегда_ используйте bind_param http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php в PDO это немного проще, потому что можно вместо bind передавать параметры запроса прямо execute

Comment: @Mike Я думал,  что именованные параметры `:id, :pass, :name` типа лучше.